# ElasticSearch aggregate information grouped by month

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am working on an ElasticSearch query that should give me back all documents where a date field is now-1 year ago and then group them all by month (giving me total count for each month), but am failing on writing this query.

This is what I have:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "account_id": [
              1
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "growth": {
      "date_range": {
        "field": "member_since",
        "format": "YYYY-MM-DD",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "to": "now-1Y/M"
          },
          {
            "from": "now-1Y/M"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 100
}
```

I am running the query like so:

`POST https://my-es-cluster-url.com`, but I keep getting this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parse_exception",
        "reason": "unit [Y] not supported for date math [-1Y/M]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query_fetch",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "index0",
        "node": "MkypXlGdQamAplca1JIgZQ",
        "reason": {
          "type": "parse_exception",
          "reason": "unit [Y] not supported for date math [-1Y/M]"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Comment: which version of ES are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your problem with a simpler query on my data.

```
"query": {
    "range": {
       "recent_buy_transaction": {
          "from": "now-1Y"
       }
    }
}
```

I get the same error.

> ElasticSearchParseException[unit [Y] not supported for date math [-1Y]]

However, using small **y** fixes the problem. Hence, you should try using:

> now-1y/M

From the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math)

> The supported time units are: y (year), M (month), w (week), d (day), h (hour), m (minute), and s (second).